# using sql nvarchar(50) as date variable in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, nvarchar

hi guys i have column that is Nvarchar(50) that i use it as a date type column because i use Persian calendar now i want to select times from two different time for example show me data s that are between 2012/12/18 and 2012/12/20 how could i do that please help and by the way i want use Stored Procedures for these actions i try this but it dose not return any thing

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sel_monthReport] @fdate nvarchar(50),@sdate nvarchar(50),@para   nvarchar(50)
as
begin
declare  @parametr nvarchar(50)
set @parametr=@para
select * from main where @parametr>=@fdate and @parametr <=@sdate
end
```

Comment: Picking a data type based on how users want to *view* the data is rarely a good idea. It would be better to use `datetime` within the database and convert to/from Persian at the front end.

Comment: Wow interesting http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranian_calendars and there is a converter in the microsoft stack http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a column in your `main` table called RecordDate, and this column is of type nvarchar, with the date format yyyy/mm/dd.

In that case, you don't need the @para parameter in your stored procedure. Change it to something like this:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[Sel_monthreport] @fdate NVARCHAR(50), 
                                   @sdate NVARCHAR(50) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT * 
      FROM   main 
      WHERE  main.recorddate BETWEEN @fdate AND @sdate 
  END
```

Note, that this is a NVARCHAR comparison, ant it only works because your dates are stored in the format yyyy/mm/dd. In general, a better approach would be to compare DATETIME datatypes (better performance and less error-prone).

You can convert an NVARCHAR value to a DATETIME datatype using the CONVERT function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: it dosent give any error but also it dosent show anything too the result is 0

Comment: what values are you entering in the `@fdate` and `@sdate` parameters? What are the values of your `RecordDate` column? Does it work if you execute the `SELECT`-statement directly, for example `SELECT * FROM main WHERE main.RecordDate BETWEEN '2012/12/18' AND '2012/12/20'`?

Comment: see all the values i enter is date with the format of yyyy/mm/dd and it works for spicific date for example 2012/12/18 but it dosent work for period of time like what i said above pls help me

Comment: Its work now you were right when i insert my data i should add a zero to the date that are less than 10 for example except 2012/12/8 i should enter 2012/12/08 by the way thank you

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been asked on StackOverflow before. As you note, out of the box, SQL Server does not support Persian. In the examples on the links on this answer ([How to convert datetime in persian in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706692/how-to-convert-datetime-in-persian-in-sql-server)), the date is stored in the database as SQL Server date format, but converted back/forward to Persian date format. You could extend these UDF examples to instead be datetime format.

Another alternative would be to write a CLR date/time function to do the same. There's an [example on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28129/Creating-a-CLR-Persian-Date-Convertor-Function-for). Either way, it's probably not best to store the dates in SQL Server as text format.