# SQL Server built-in func for Converting Persian date to Gregorian date

Tags: sql-server

I just started learning SQL Server. does SQL Server has an built-in function to convert the Persian date to Gregorian date? (like: `format(getdate() , 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'fa-ir')`. this func is for convert the Gregorian date to Persian date)

***Note:*** I know there are many ways to convert the Persian date to Gregorian date (like using a predefined table or write t-sql for this convert e.g: [How to convert Persian date into Gregorian date in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381565/how-to-convert-persian-date-into-gregorian-date-in-sql-server)),  ***BUT I'm LOOKING FOR AN BUILT-IN FUNCTION***

Any and all feedback is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Persian date into Gregorian date in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381565/how-to-convert-persian-date-into-gregorian-date-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Larnu I checked all the answers in StackOverFlow but I did not find any built-in func

Comment: Yes, because there isn't one; you need to add your own (as the dupe candidate demonstrates).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Persian date into Gregorian date in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381565/how-to-convert-persian-date-into-gregorian-date-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Charlieface plz read above comments. thanks

Comment: There isn't a built-in function, sorry.