# how to convert persian number to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-conversion

There is a nvarchar(100) column named `value`, when users insert into this column I need to check this code below in a trigger:

```
if exists
(
    select *
    from inserted i
    where isnumeric(value)=0
)
begin
    rollback transaction
    raiserror('when productType is numeric, You have to insert numeric character',18,1)
    return
end
```

but in application interface numbers inserted in persian, so always `isnumeric(value)=0`.

For example I need to if user insert `۴۵` in interface in my trigger value shown as `45`.

So far I use `CAST`,`CONVERT` and `collate Persian_100_CI_AI` but I couldn't get any result.

Thanks.

Comment: Persian numbers are just text to SQL Server. Convert the number client side or look for a SQL Server extension (like a UDF or CLR UDF). See this [question about Persian dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706692/how-to-convert-datetime-in-persian-in-sql-server).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Which version of `SQL Server`? v2017+ offers a [new function `TRANSLATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql).

Might be, there is a more elegant way, but a pragmatic one is this:

```
DECLARE @PersianNumber NVARCHAR(100)=N'۴۵';
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE
           (@PersianNumber,N'۰',N'0'),N'۱',N'1'),N'۲',N'2'),N'۳',N'3'),N'۴',N'4')
                          ,N'۵',N'5'),N'۶',N'6'),N'۷',N'7'),N'۸',N'8'),N'۹',N'9') AS INT);
```

Comment: So it's just the characters that are different? Nice one

Comment: @Andomar, to be honest: I hope so :-)  (and a short research let it look like this...)

Comment: Thanks man! it does work correctly but Instead of this solution I use 10 separate replace and I check both of them with client statistics, it does have a better time result separately! Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this topic, it's the opposite of what you asked but it might help you if you could reverse it :

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a44ce5c1-d487-4043-be73-b64fa98ed7a5/converting-english-numbers-to-arabic-numbers-and-vice-versa

If you are using the latest version of sql server, try this link :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql

the obvious thing is that SQL does not have a solution out-of-the-box and you have to implement some kind of function yourself and use the returned value in the `WHERE` statement.

I have used Shungo's answer to implement the function you need (also works for English numbers or a mix of both):

```
CREATE FUNCTION IS_NORMALIZED_NUMBER (@PersianNumber NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
    SET @PersianNumber = CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE
           (@PersianNumber,N'۰',N'0'),N'۱',N'1'),N'۲',N'2'),N'۳',N'3'),N'۴',N'4')
                          ,N'۵',N'5'),N'۶',N'6'),N'۷',N'7'),N'۸',N'8'),N'۹',N'9') AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
    RETURN ISNUMERIC(@PersianNumber)
END
```

Here is a more optimized version (which will only work for Persian numbers) :

```
CREATE FUNCTION IS_NUMBER (@PersianNumber NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
    RETURN IIF(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE
           (@PersianNumber,N'۰',N''),N'۱',N''),N'۲',N''),N'۳',N''),N'۴',N'')
                          ,N'۵',N''),N'۶',N''),N'۷',N''),N'۸',N''),N'۹',N'') = N'',1 ,0 );
END
```

Comment: here is another topic that might help you http://forums.devshed.com/asp-programming-51/help-converting-arabic-english-63697.html

Comment: thank you man I didn't know that, I will check this out absolutely! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TRANSLATE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('1234', '0123456789',  N'٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩') AS KurdishNumber
```