# SQL Server doesn't recognize Arabic number in integer column

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using SQL Server 2017 and when I want to insert Arabic digit inside a int column it gives me error.

[image]

Comment: You cannot save unicode value into integer column, you have to convert arabic number into english and then save it to int column while getting value you need to convert english number into arabic

Answer (score 1):

AS stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49511465/how-to-convert-persian-number-to-int)

Which version of `SQL Server`? v2017+ offers a [new function `TRANSLATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql).

Might be, there is a more elegant way, but a pragmatic one is this:

```
DECLARE @PersianNumber NVARCHAR(100)=N'۴۵';
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE
           (@PersianNumber,N'۰',N'0'),N'۱',N'1'),N'۲',N'2'),N'۳',N'3'),N'۴',N'4')
                          ,N'۵',N'5'),N'۶',N'6'),N'۷',N'7'),N'۸',N'8'),N'۹',N'9') AS INT);
```