# Show Persian date format in datagridview from Gregorian date format of SQL Server Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpfdatagrid

I have a PersianDate Picker component.it takes a Persian format date like`1397/4/27`  and I can convert it to  Gregorian date by this code:

```
var dt1 = calender_From.SelectedDate.ToDateTime();
```

that saved like `2018-07-16 00:00:00.000` in SQL Server database.

Now,I want to convert a Gregorian format Date like`2018-07-16 00:00:00.000` to Persian format date like`1397/4/27`,While The code want to run (in VS-2015) and a DataGridView want takes the date from SQL Server database.

I use C# and I'm programming in VS 2015.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert datetime in persian in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706692/how-to-convert-datetime-in-persian-in-sql-server)

Comment: No,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706692/how-to-convert-datetime-in-persian-in-sql-server did not solved my problem