# How to specify the value of the selected field with type date displayed Jalali (Shamsi) instead of date miladi (Gregorian Date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to specify the value of the selected field with type **date** displayed Jalali (Shamsi) instead of date miladi (Gregorian Date) in SQL server management

For example:

> Instead of 2018-11-05,    I want display 1397-08-14

[image: for example show Jalali (Shamsi) instead of date miladi (Gregorian Date)]

for example display Jalali (Shamsi) instead of date miladi (Gregorian Date) in photo

Comment: Surprisingly already answered...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706692/how-to-convert-datetime-in-persian-in-sql-server