# Convert int format to date and find difference in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains below columns; my main request is to achieve difference between {enddate} and {startdate}.

My dates are saved in database as `int` and my date is Persian date I need find a way to fill {Experiment_Year}, {Experiment_Month} and {Experiment_Day} columns with the value of date actually I need something that works like datediff function.

I already try to split in year moth and day but fail because moth doesn't work
substring doesn't work too. Does anyone one have any idea?

```
Start_Date  End_Date    Experiment_Year Experiment_Month Experiment_Day
----------- ----------- --------------- ---------------- --------------
890101      891001      0               0                0
890101      891001      0               0                0
891001      891101      0               0                0
891101      900101      0               0                0
900101      910101      0               0                0
900101      910101      0               0                0
910101      910114      0               0                0
910114      920101      0               0                0
920101      920601      0               0                0
920101      920601      0               0                0
```

My failed code:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(CAST(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), se.endDate), 2) AS INT) - 
       CAST(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), se.startdate), 2) AS INT) AS NVARCHAR),    
    CAST(DATEDIFF(mm, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, se.startdate, se.enddate), se.startdate), se.enddate) AS VARCHAR(2)),
    CAST(DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, se.startdate, se.enddate), se.startdate), se.enddate), DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, se.startdate, se.enddate), se.startdate)),se.enddate) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS result
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         startdate, enddate 
     FROM
         cnv_hr_Duty_His_sequence 
     WHERE
         EmpID = 16017) se
```

or

```
CASE
   WHEN se.endDate IS NULL
      THEN NULL
      ELSE CAST(CAST(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),se.endDate), 2) as int) - cast( LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),se.startdate), 2) as int) as nvarchar)
                --CAST(DATEDIFF(yy, convert(datetime,se.startdate), convert(datetime,se.enddate)) AS varchar(4))
                --CAST(('13' + SUBSTRING(CAST(se.endDate AS NVARCHAR), 1, 2)) AS INT) - CAST(('13' + SUBSTRING(CAST(se.startdate AS NVARCHAR), 1, 2)) AS INT)
            END Experiment_Year,

                    cast(cast(right(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),se.endDate), 4),2) as int) - cast( right(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),se.startdate), 4),2) as int) as nvarchar)

            Experiment_Month,
            CASE
                WHEN se.endDate IS NULL
                THEN NULL
                ELSE cast(cast(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),se.endDate), 2) as int) - cast( RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),se.startdate), 2) as int) as nvarchar)
            END Experiment_Day,
```

my desire result :

```
Start_Date  End_Date    Experiment_Year                Experiment_Month               Experiment_Day
    ----------- ----------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
    890101      891001      0                              9                              0
    890101      891001      0                              9                              0
    891001      891101      0                              1                              0
    891101      900101      0                              1                            0
    900101      910101      1                              0                              0
    900101      910101      1                              0                              0
    910101      910114      0                              0                              13
    910114      920101      0                              11                              16
    920101      920601      0                              5                              0
    920101      920601      0                              5                              0
```

Comment: Please describe what the format of the date is.  What date does 890101 represent?  If you are dealing with Persian dates, then you might be interested in :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706692/how-to-convert-datetime-in-persian-in-sql-server.

Comment: 1389/01/01 it represent's Persian date this date equal is 2010-03-21 but i have just this